# VTK Smartpointer New()

Tags: vtk

I am using VTK for Visualization and my code is full of their smartpointers, like:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
```

what I was wondering about if this `New()` should not be followed later by `Delete()`. Or does
VTK destroy everything "automatically". Many times by using `Delete()` my code crashes. So, I was wondering if I should use it in first place and what is behind `New()`, a shared pointer or something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

vtkSmartPointer will destroy the object "automatically" when out of scope. The Delete() method is called in the dtor of it.

Without vtkSmartPointer, you need to take care the memory management issues by yourself and call Delete(), like following

```
vtkObject* MyObject = vtkObject::New();
MyObject->Delete();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkObject> MyObject = vtkSmartPointer<vtkObject>::New();
```

See the wiki page: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/SmartPointers

Comment: It should be noted that there are a couple of other smart pointer classes in VTK, vtkNew gives a strongly scoped smart pointer object with automatic object creation and vtkWeakPointer offers a weak reference where it will not delete the object but will return null if the object was deleted elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative to

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkObject> MyObject = vtkSmartPointer<vtkObject>::New();
```

is

```
vtkNew<vtkObject> MyObject;
```

Just note that when passing MyObject to functions/methods that take in a vtkObject*, you have to use MyObject.GetPointer() e.g.

```
foo->SetObject(MyObject.GetPointer());
```